# ionic1 textbox floats up higher when onfocus

Tags: android, html, ios, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic1 app and there's an issue with my keyboard though i've install the keyboard plugin. When i focus on a text field it floats up way higher and at times blocking the user's view. 
Below is an image of how it looks

[image]

Script

```
<form name="sendMessageForm" ng-submit="sendMessage(data.message)" novalidate>
      <ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable item-input-inset message-footer" keyboard-attach>
          <label class="item-input-wrapper">
              <input id="msg-input" ng-change="updateTyping()" ng-model="message" class="input-message" type="text" placeholder="Message" autocomplete="off">
          </label>
          <div class="footer-btn-wrap">
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-paperplane footer-btn" type="submit" ng-click="send()"
                ng-disabled="!message || message === ''">
            </button>
          </div>
      </ion-footer-bar>
  </form>
```

tested in both iOS and android and have the same results

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this CSS to the style's form:

```css
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```